# How is the Geekbench score of Snapdragon 865 greater than Intel i7 7700HQ?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking, intel, cpu-architecture, qualcomm

Also, are there any valid methods/metrics to compare the equivalent performance (throughput) of an Intel(amd64) & a Snapdragon(ARM) processor?

The following are the links that show the **Geekbench scores** of i7-7700HQ and Snapdragon 865 (OnePlus 8):

i7-7700HQ: https://browser.geekbench.com/processors/intel-core-i7-7700hq (Score: 3300)

Snapdragon 865 (OP8): https://browser.geekbench.com/android_devices/oneplus-8 (Score: 3320)

**Overall Rankings** (check the muti-core scores):

Android: https://browser.geekbench.com/android-benchmarks

Processors: https://browser.geekbench.com/processor-benchmarks

Comment: It's an 8-core CPU (https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/qualcomm/snapdragon_800/865) vs. 4 for Intel, although to be fair 4 of those cores are "low power" cortex-A55.  Still, depending on what Geekbench is even measuring, that could make a big difference.  I assume it's not measuring high-throughput floating point math or video encoding.